# Android Notification Vibration/LED doesn't work?

Tags: android

Hi I have looked at the documentation about notifications but it is of no help.  I followed the advice and applied it to the following class:  (the issue is commented)
I wanted to apply a vibration and/LED accompanying the status bar notification( status bar notification does work). When I follow the documentation advice, it states I have to insert :otification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;     But I get an error saying that notification cannot be resolved to a variable and if I change "notification" to note.notification, I don't get any notification at all.  The application only runs If I delete the lines I've commented for you. I am not sure where I am going wrong?  Thanks.

public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {

```
public ReminderService() {
    super("ReminderService");
        }

@Override
void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("ReminderService", "Doing work.");
    Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ReminderEditActivity.class); 
    notificationIntent.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId); 

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

    Notification note=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), System.currentTimeMillis());
    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, getString(R.string.notify_new_task_title), getString(R.string.notify_new_task_message), pi);
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

//This is where I'm having problems

```
    **notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
    notification.ledOnMS = 300;
    notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;**
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where exactly do you define notification? Your Notification instance is the note object, notificiation is thus undefined.

**To solve your problem, just replace all notification reference with note.**

Comment: Hi I replaced them all with a note for a test.  When I ran the application, no notification of the sort came up.

Comment: Did you check that you correctly pass the notification to the NotificationManager?

Comment: By the way, the Notification constructor is deprecated, you should use the Notification.Builder: [Notification API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)

Comment: Thank you!  I shall try this.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks!  It's just that the status bar notification works, it's only when I try to add the vibration and LED light functions that causes problems.

Comment: Sorted it now :)  Thanks for your help!